# Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair'

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ppa

I had Ubuntu 13.10 installed on my laptop. After I upgraded windows, I tried to get grub back through `Boot Repair` via these commands mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/182863):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

But when I run first command I get this error:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

what's the problem?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1050824/158369 and in BIOS only UEFI option for boot-repair

Comment: Note: It seems obvious, but make sure internet is connected. I've forgotten this several times when using the live disk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest you to do in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

and then do:

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

if it doesn't work I would suggest you to add it manually in apt-get

```
nano /etc/apt/source.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-saucy.list
```

and write  this:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu saucy main

then save it and update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: do you mean ... etc/apt/sources.list.d/....   (note the S at the end of the word sources)?

Comment: In 18.10 BIOS have to be only UEFI and [trusted=yes] after deb: deb [trusted=yes]  http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu cosmic main

Answer (score 26):

This specific issue occurs when you live boot and try to do add the ppa before being connected to the internet.

Simply connect to the internet first and then try to add the ppa again just like before.

Comment: LOL yes you're right, I have no internet :facepalm:

Comment: I can also add that you may need to reopen terminal if after connecting to internet it still gives same error.