# APT complains about bad signature and security when adding repository and packages cannot be installed

Tags: apt, package-management

After running the command `sudo apt-get update` in my terminal I have some errors:

```
Hit:1 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu artful InRelease
Get:3 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease [237 kB]      
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease [78,6 kB]
Err:3 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                     
  The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
Hit:5 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease
Get:6 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease [72,2 kB]
Reading package lists... Done      
W: GPG error: http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
E: The repository 'http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

If I ignore it and try

```
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev nodejs yarn
```

I get more errors and the packages are not installed

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sqlite3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package zlib1g-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package nodejs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package python-software-properties is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  software-properties-common

E: Unable to locate package git-core
E: Package 'zlib1g-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libreadline-dev
E: Unable to locate package libyaml-dev
E: Unable to locate package libsqlite3-dev
E: Package 'sqlite3' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libxslt1-dev
E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libffi-dev
E: Package 'nodejs' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force update from unsigned repository Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732985/force-update-from-unsigned-repository-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: It's usually a very bad idea to add repositories from other distributions. Why did you add that repository? What instructions were you following? Mixing repositories breaks things...

Comment: im done with the image, can you help me?

Comment: karel im done with all code on that's thread and still error

Answer (score 0):

The system says that there is unsigned repository "http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful".

**Try this command:**
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32

It must solve your problem.

Comment: im done with it but still error

Comment: Could you say about the output of the command? It was like this: 
 `Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/user/0/tmp.OykkQtm4Ui --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
gpg: requesting key C0B21F32 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key C0B21F32: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" 11 new signatures
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:         new signatures: 11
`