# Broadcom WIFI adapter works in live USB but not in installation

Tags: boot, wireless, system-installation, live-usb

on my Desktop I have a Broadcom wifi adapter. When I boot from live USB 18.04 I go to Software & Updates, then *Additional Drivers* and enable it, straightforward and easy. If I install it then on the SSD (with the option of downloading restricted packages and hardware support and wifi enabled(meaning it can download all it needs))) I end up with a system without the wifi drivers. The same `Additional Drivers` enabling doesn't work.

Running:

```
cd /cdrom/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source*
```

to install the driver from the Live USB fails because of dependency issues and the Ubuntu Docs are outdated, i.e. folders they mention don't exist anymore on the live USB.

[Ubuntu Docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)

So it works in the live USB, but doesn't in the installation. How can I fix it?

Comment: "fails because of dependency issues" Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Is the missing dependency `dkms`? It's on the Live USB also. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: One is `dkms`, so I copy that from the live USB to `/`, do `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`, then it complains about needing `libc6-v`, another one is `gcc`. It works out of the box on the live USB and should just carry over on the real install. Is the best thing I can do really trying to follow all the dependencies, assemble them in a folder and do `dpkg -i *.deb`? I don't have a wired  connection available.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue trying to get my HP Stream 11 (model: `11-r015wm`) netbook connected to WiFi.

`lshw -C network` told me it was a Broadcom BCM43142 wireless card. Come to find out it's a WiFi + Bluetooth combo card with (anecdotally - I tried about 6 different Linux distros) not a lot of support out of the box.

I settled on using [Ubuntu Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/) and similar to your experience, when running from the live CD, I could get the wireless card to work if I manually downloaded and installed the driver and some dependencies:

`bcmwl-kernel-source`, `linux-libc-dev`, `libc6-dev` & `dkms` .deb packages. It was like magic when on the last command `sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb` my WiFi turned on and starting working.

I naively thought all I needed to do now was to install the OS from the live CD and install those same .deb packages. With my new and working internet connection I installed the OS on my hard drive and made sure to tick off the box about installing updates and third party software/drivers.

However, after I finished the installation and restarting, this time around when I attempted to install `dkms` it said I was missing `dpkg-dev`, `make` & `gcc`. Wait what? *Perhaps the live CD contains more software or is more robust than a standard installation?*

Anyways, I started to manually install each dependency as they came up by going to https://pkgs.org/ and transferring over the .deb files with a USB. By my fourth transfer I was pretty salty.

This is what I did to finally end up solving the issue:

**1)** Found and downloaded my driver with all of its dependencies to a USB using this method:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008193/how-to-list-download-the-recursive-dependencies-of-a-debian-package

**1.5)** Then I attempted to install all of the .deb packages and resolve dependencies by adding a local directory to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

reference:
https://www.linuxwave.info/2009/04/adding-local-directory-to-apt.html

I then ran `sudo apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated`

reference:
[Force update from unsigned repository Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732985/force-update-from-unsigned-repository-ubuntu-16-04#732987)

However, my package dependencies were still not resolving correctly. I was trying to run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` on the folder where I saved everything but dpkg wasn't sure about which order to process all my .deb files in. So I tried something else instead..

**2)** I copied all of my .deb files into `/var/cache/apt/archives` and followed the answer here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366488/how-to-use-dpkg-i-to-install-package-and-dependencies-where-dependencies-are-al#366886

by running `sudo apt-get install -f` it installed all of my dependencies and my WiFi finally turned on.

What a mess! And I'm quite surprised about the inconsistency between booting from a live CD vs installing and booting from my hard drive.