# Updating From Non-Secure Respository

Tags: package-management, updates, 19.10, repository

Recently, I have been getting this error every time I perform `sudo apt-get update`. I surmise that I have messed up a repository package download by cancelling it before it was fully installed.

```
"Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I've searched and searched online and cannot find a solution; I've tried `--allow-unauthenticated` but get response `command not found`.
I'm running Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Can you add the full output ? Is it appear that some repository is outdated, run `sudo apt-get update` and paste full output here.

Comment: it seems the details are too long. could i email you the details?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output to it.

Comment: @marnec Just [edit] the question, and append the output here. Don't forget to use `<code>` tags, or simply Ctrl + K.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force update from unsigned repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732985/force-update-from-unsigned-repository)

Comment: Please refer [to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732985/force-update-from-unsigned-repository) for general use. If you're using an additional repository, I found [adding this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1050824/212930) to your sources was a good workaround.