# unable to install cudo miner to ubuntu

Tags: sudo, gnome-terminal, add-apt-repository

**what i am trying to run:**

`sudo su -c "bash <(wget -qO- https://download.cudo.org/tenants/135790374f46b0107c516a5f5e13069b/5e5f800fdf87209fdf8f9b61441e53a1/linux/x64/stable/install.sh)" root`

**what error pops up**

````
--2021-03-23 08:41:25--  https://download.cudo.org/keys/pgp/apt.asc
Resolving download.cudo.org (download.cudo.org)... 104.26.10.102, 104.26.11.102, 172.67.69.190, ...
Connecting to download.cudo.org (download.cudo.org)|104.26.10.102|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3146 (3.1K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                   100%[===================>]   3.07K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2021-03-23 08:41:25 (64.2 MB/s) - written to stdout [3146/3146]

Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:5 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease          
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu focal InRelease      
Hit:7 http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease                                     
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:9 http://dell.archive.canonical.com focal InRelease                        
Hit:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease              
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:12 https://download.cudo.org/repo/apt stable InRelease                     
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu focal Release       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Hit:14 https://debrepo.freedownloadmanager.org bionic InRelease
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.```
````

**What have i tried:**

*[Force update from unsigned repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732985/force-update-from-unsigned-repository)*

*https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/bm85q9/how_do_i_enable_updates_from_insecure_repositories/*

Comment: I had a look at one PPA you added; it's support ended in 2013; that's a long time ago. PPA's are 3rd party sources, so all security checks are your responsibility, and it looks like you failed to perform them (20.04 or the 2020-April release didn't exist in 2013)

Comment: @guiverc thanks it solved the problem