# 'apt-get update' stopped working and gives unsigned repo message. any ideas how this happened?

Tags: apt, updates, repository

solved:
apt-transport-https must have been corrupted or some other similar issue. (i am not sure if this previous sentence actually had anything to do with the successful repair, but i did it, so i am documenting) then used apt-get purge remove apt-transport-https, and followed the checked answer to complete my repair of the issue.

original:
I am running ubuntu 21.10 and apt-get update stopped working, here is the output:

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease [90.7 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease [90.7 kB]
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease           
Err:4 https://dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian stable InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 52.42.128.10 443]
Reading package lists... Done                  
E: Failed to fetch https://deb.etcher.io/dists/stable/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 52.42.128.10 443]
E: The repository 'https://deb.etcher.io stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any ideas why this would have suddenly started happening? And how to repair it?

Comment: I'm gonna guess that using the debian repo is causing you some issues, and that you should remove it from your list of sources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force update from unsigned repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732985/force-update-from-unsigned-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message refers to the [Balena Etcher PPA that has been deprecated.](https://www.linux.org/threads/problems-with-balena-etchers-ppa.34395/)

Remove the old PPA amd add the new one according to the instructions linked above and reproduced here:

```
curl -1sLf \
'https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/setup.deb.sh' \
| sudo -E bash
```

If you have Balena Etcher already installed it'll will be upgrade alongside the other updates.

Comment: i am sorry, i am not sure how to post or respond appropriately, let me know if there is a better way and how to correct...

Comment: here is the beginning out my output from the suggested instructions:   'https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/setup.deb.sh' \
   | sudo -E bash
Executing the  setup script for the 'balena/etcher' repository ...

Comment: >>>>: ... distro=ubuntu  version=21.10  codename=impish  arch=x86_64  
 >>>>:
 NOPE: Checking for apt dependency 'apt-transport-https' ...
 NOPE: Updating apt repository metadata cache ...
Failed to update via apt-get update
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease [90.7 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease [90.7 kB]
Err:1 https://dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian stable InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 34.209.144.48 443]

Comment: E: Failed to fetch https://deb.etcher.io/dists/stable/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 34.209.144.48 443]
E: The repository 'https://deb.etcher.io stable InRelease' is not signed.
 ^^^^: ... Failed to update via apt-get update - Context above.
 !!!!: Oh no, your setup failed! :-( ... But we might be able to help. :-)
 !!!!: 
 !!!!: You can contact balena for further assistance.
 !!!!: 
 !!!!: URL: https://github.com/balena-io/etcher
 !!!!:

Comment: It seems it hasn't been updated for 'impish' yet. It works fine for 20.04 and 21.04 though. You may want to remove the old PPA anyway (because the script couldn't). Open Software & Updates > Other software and you'll find it there.

Comment: your suggestion previously helped remove several error messages. the final one that was left said that apt-transport-https dependency was not working. it would not update and didnt register as existing (i think). first, i went to apt and removed balena-etcher.list, then i used:    sudo apt-get --purge remove apt-transport-https      and then followed with: sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https.  That fixed the issue to where the rest of your advice fell into place, i ran the commands you gave, then ran the install per instructions on balena's git page.

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome :)