# sudo apt-get update fails to securely connect to repositories, cannot update anything

Tags: apt, 20.04

I reinstalled Ubuntu Gamepack after accidentally wiping it from my SSD, and I needed to update GNOME to properly boot into it.

I've looked at several other threads and tried those solutions, but nothing has panned out for me. I have some functions that aren't working for me, such as my mouse disconnecting after a certain amount of time, all audio in/out devices not registering after restarting Discord, among other software issues.

If nothing else pans out, I'm considering reinstalling, although that may create more problems than it solves.

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:5 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal InRelease         
Get:6 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease [4,502 B]                    
Hit:7 http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/release/2.4 bionic InRelease     
Get:8 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease [2,590 B]            
Hit:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:10 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                    
Ign:11 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:12 https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:13 https://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease           
Hit:14 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Release
Hit:15 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                        
Err:16 https://ppa.laucnchpad.net/jarnos/ppa-purge/ubuntu eoan InRelease       
  Could not resolve 'ppa.laucnchpad.net'
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu focal InRelease  
Hit:18 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                
Hit:20 http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease                                    
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Err:6 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                              
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
Hit:23 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                      
Hit:24 http://deb.playonlinux.com bionic InRelease                             
Get:25 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_20.04 ./ InRelease [2,441 B]     
Err:8 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                      
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DD3C368A8DE1B7A0
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/costales/folder-color/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease            
Hit:19 https://archive.ualinux.com/deb all InRelease                           
Hit:21 https://archive.ualinux.com/deb ubuntupack InRelease                    
Hit:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-7-0/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libretro/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:35 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unit193/encryption/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                                
W: GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
E: The repository 'https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DD3C368A8DE1B7A0
E: The repository 'https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Why do you have so many package repos? I get having a few additional ones... but first consider if you really need all of those, and remove the ones you don't need. If you really want to update even though it is insecure, you can, _but it is insecure, so you probobly shouldn't_. See [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/732985/1438484) that explains how to bypass the security warning.

Comment: I don't know why either, I'm new to Linux. I also have not done much inside the terminal, so apologies if I'm a bit confused. I've tried what you have suggested, and this is what I got: https://pastebin.com/jkyuQvwd

Comment: Many of the PPAs weren't added by you directly but added when you *installed* some software (Chrome, Opera, Skype, CUDA/Nvidia, ...). Of those Opera and Skype have problems. I suggest you google both error messages and then you'll learn something new :) (it's just one command to retrieve the missing or expired keys). There's one you added that is obviously wrong, just remove it (and 'ppa-purge' is in the official repos, no need to add a PPA anyway).

Comment: You have to open Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and then disable repositories for Skype and Opera. Then retry running `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: I have done as you said N0rbert, and now I can update some items. I'm getting signature errors, but I think I can figure it out from here. I'll comment again if I need any additional help

Comment: Well, I'm coming back again. I'm using the same fork of Linux as last time, and it's says something along the lines of "UbuntuGamePack doesn't have an official release file. updating can't be done securely, and we disabled it."
I'm using this on a USB stick, so that may be the issue. I'll update this when I test this on my PC